# terminal context not updating in nodejs child process

Tags: java, node.js, terminal, child-process

Part of this program checks if java is installed and continues checking every two seconds, then proceeds once it's installed, how do i make it update the terminal context to be able to execute the java command without restarting the program itself?

```
var javaCheckLoop = setInterval(function(){

    checkJava(function(res){

        if(res){
            //java installed, continue
        } else {
            //java not found, keep checking
        }

    })

},2000)


function checkJava(callback) {

    //need terminal context to update so it can detect java
    var c = require('child_process').exec('java', (error, stdout, stderr) => {

        callback(stderr.includes("Usage")); //returns true if java is available via cmd

    });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while I did find a way to detect if java had been installed I didn't find a way to update the terminal context. I was previously trying to spawn java as a command, but the trick lied in the registry, which updates in real time and can be used to detect if java had been installed.

```js
require('child_process').exec('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment"', (error, data) => {

            callback(String(data).includes("javapath")); //returns true if javapath is present in the environment variables

});
```